# unexpected token:'not' error for SOQL

Tags: apex, soql

I am using below query but getting error saying unexpected token 'not'.

```
[Select ID, Email, LastLoginDate ,createddate,Reactivation_Date__c,
isportalenabled,TEST_CREATED_DATE__C,TEST_LOGIN_DATE__C  
from User where Functional_System_User__c=false and isActive =true 
 and ID=:U.Id not in :frozenIDList 
ORDER BY LastLoginDate ASC NULLS LAST];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your where clause is

```
where Functional_System_User__c=false 
      and isActive =true 
      and ID=:U.Id not in :frozenIDList
```

Its complaining about the not because you don't say which field should not be in the list, if you remove the other valid conditions you have

```
where not in :frozenIDList
```

you need to say which field, e.g.

```
where id not in :frozenIDList
```

expanding back out to your original query, you'd get

```
[Select ID, Email, LastLoginDate ,createddate,Reactivation_Date__c,
isportalenabled,TEST_CREATED_DATE__C,TEST_LOGIN_DATE__C  
from User where Functional_System_User__c=false and isActive =true 
and ID=:U.Id AND ID not in :frozenIDList 
ORDER BY LastLoginDate ASC NULLS LAST]
```

Comment: I had used list<id> and above query also i used but it gave error.Now i have changed to list<user> then above query worked fine.Thanks simon and superfell.

Answer (score 1):

You've missed the "and" from before your NOT IN, where you want to check if that ID is in the list.

```
[SELECT ID, Email, LastLoginDate, createddate, Reactivation_Date__c,
isportalenabled, TEST_CREATED_DATE__C, TEST_LOGIN_DATE__C  
FROM User
WHERE Functional_System_User__c=false
AND isActive=true 
AND ID=:U.Id
AND ID NOT IN :frozenIDList 
ORDER BY LastLoginDate ASC NULLS LAST];
```